# Silverlight Error 263 Domain operation entry 'MyOperation' must take exactly one parameter

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, ria

I have a Silverlight application that is using RIA Services. However, I need a service operation that takes multiple parameters. My operation looks like the following:

```
public void MyOperation(string userName, bool isActive, string emailAddress)
{
  // Do Stuff           
}
```

As it stands now, I get an error that says:
*Error  263 Domain operation entry 'MyOperation' must take exactly one parameter.*

My question is, how do I create a service operation tht takes multiple parameters in a RIA Services service?  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code that you provided works for me (as is). However, there will be an error if your operation's name isn't really `MyOperation`, but rather something like `InsertOperation` or `AddOperation` or something that falls into "CRUD" (Create Read Update Delete operations). That is caused some conventions in the RIA Services (which you can read about [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707373(v=VS.91).aspx)).

To work around that, you can either use a name that doesn't fall into those conventions, or you can specify the operation to be an *Invoke Operation* by using the `InvokeAttribute` like so:

```
[Invoke]
public void AddOperation(string userName, bool isActive, string emailAddress)
{
    // Do Stuff           
}
```

Hope this helps :)